# adding sys arguments in the code to use in any imported module

Tags: python, pytest

my module require some sys arguments for instantiation:

```
print('args are: \t')
print(sys.argv)
d_path = sys.argv[2]
test2 = sys.argv[1]
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[2]))
```

if I want to import this module in pytest,i am not able to pass these arguments.
Although, we can argument to pytest,but those are argument specific to pytest framework.We need to way to pass these sys argument using pytest

Comment: Please provide sample of your pytest code.

Comment: @SilentGuy I got solution.thanks for asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can set arguments using following code

```
sys.argv.append("ad")
sys.argv.append("ert")
```

or

```
args=["rwsr","sfff"]
  sys.argv[1:]=args
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>read_args.py
import sys
print('args for read_args are: \t')
test2,d_path=sys.argv[1:3]
print(f"d_path:{d_path}, test2:{test2}")

>pytest.py
import sys
import read_args
sys.argv[1:]=sys.argv[3:]
print('args of pytest are: \t')
print(sys.argv)
```

**$python pytest.py 1 2 3 4**

*args for read_args are:*

*d_path:2, test2:1*

*args of pytest are:*

*['pytest.py', '3', '4']*